# I can sign with using passport local, but it does NOT save my login when I refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, passport.js

So, I am building a passport authentication app with MERN Stack. I have my backend API set up and a few react components going. I was able to successfully sign in using passport local, but it wont keep me logged in when I refresh the page. When I inspect the chrome browser, its like it doesn't save cookies. Although, when I check my mongo database cluster, it has sessions saved each time I log in. I'm doing something wrong here and I'm not sure what it is.

My backend code is found here https://github.com/astonjones/backend-to-passport/commits/master

My frontend code is found here https://github.com/astonjones/frontend-of-passport-app

I am using mongoose, express, express-session, passport, passport-local. I am also using 'connect-mongo' for the session secret saves. Should I be using a different kind of session save instead?

Here's a pic of the session saving:
[Session Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsIwy.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe saveInitialize should be true?

Comment: I attempted that and It didn't fix the issue. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

change the option session resave:true